# Android studio IDE error

Tags: 16.04, android, android-studio

I've installed android studio on a ubuntu 16.04 via umake, at first it worked properly, but, for some reason i can't explain, everytime I open the IDE, it shows me an error, something like:

```
NullPointerException: Unexpected exception during symbol building (rebuildModuleMaps)
```

or sometimes the error message is:

```
NullPointerException: Unexpected exception during symbol building (rebuildSymbols)
```

I think it's something with the gradle, but I don't know how to fix it,and can't find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research myself, and it appears that this error is due to Android NDK support being disabled. Re-enabling NDK support fixed this issue for me.

To re-enable Android NDK support, go to **Settings** > **Plugins** and enable the **Android NDK Support** and **NDK WorkspaceManager Support** plugins.